# Terraform valdiate that one of N variables is set to "true"

Tags: validation, terraform

I have 4 storage class variables that are set by default to false , then set one of them in inputs to "true" . Looking for a way to validate that only one of 4 storage classes variable is set to "true".

```
variable "sc1_default" { 
  default = "false"
}

variable "sc1_default" { 
  default = "false"
}

variable "sc3_default" { 
  default = "false"
}

variable "sc4_default" { 
  default = "false"
}


   
on terraform.tfvars  Inputs

sc3_default = "true"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Option #1

We can do that with a [lifecycle precondition](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#custom-condition-checks) in a null_resource

A couple of things before we dive into the code:

- Your code has two `sc1_default` variables I'm assuming that the second one was a typo and what you meant there is `sc2_default`
- For additional validation use `type` in the variables, it's a good practice, makes the code more readable and if someone accidentally passes the wrong type the code fails gracefully.

see sample code below

```hcl
variable "sc1_default" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}

variable "sc2_default" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}

variable "sc3_default" {
  type    = bool
  default = true
}

variable "sc4_default" {
  type    = bool
  default = true
}

resource "null_resource" "validation" {
  lifecycle {
    precondition {
      condition = (
        (var.sc1_default ? 1 : 0) +
        (var.sc2_default ? 1 : 0) +
        (var.sc3_default ? 1 : 0) +
        (var.sc4_default ? 1 : 0)
      ) < 2
      error_message = "Only one sc can be true"
    }
  }
}
```

You can see I set the `sc3_default` and `sc4_default` both to true just to trigger the error ...

The condition is the core of this validation we are just adding all the true with the help of shorthand if syntax `(var.sc_default ? 1 : 0)` and the total should be less than two, I'm assuming that all false is OK, but if not you can change that logic to check that is precisely one.

A terraform plan on that code will error out with the following message:

```txt
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Resource precondition failed
│ 
│   on main.tf line 24, in resource "null_resource" "validation":
│   24:       condition = (
│   25:         (var.sc1_default ? 1 : 0) +
│   26:         (var.sc2_default ? 1 : 0) +
│   27:         (var.sc3_default ? 1 : 0) +
│   28:         (var.sc4_default ? 1 : 0)
│   29:       ) < 2
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.sc1_default is false
│     │ var.sc2_default is false
│     │ var.sc3_default is true
│     │ var.sc4_default is true
│ 
│ Only one sc can be true
```

---

## Option #2

If you can change the input variables we could reduce it to just one with a `list(bool)` the code will be smaller and the validation would be right on the variable

```hcl
variable "sc_default" {
  type        = list(bool)
  description = "list of sc default values"
  default     = [false, false, false, false]


  validation {
    condition     = length(var.sc_default) == 4
    error_message = "Four defaults expected"
  }

  validation {
    condition     = sum([for x in var.sc_default : x ? 1 : 0]) < 2
    error_message = "Only one sc can be true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to my other answer, I was just wondering how exactly are you using the storage class variables?

Instead of 4 `boolean` variables wouldn't it be easier to just declare one `string` variable and add a condition in order to accept only valid values?

For example, assuming that valid values are `sc1`, `sc2`, `sc3` and `sc4`:

```hcl
variable "storage_class" {
  type        = string
  description = "Value of storage class"

  validation {
    condition     = contains(["sc1", "sc2", "sc3", "sc4"], var.storage_class)
    error_message = "The storage_class must be one of: sc1, sc2, sc3, sc4."
  }
}
```

Running `terraform plan` with variable `storage_class="abc"`:

```txt
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Invalid value for variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 1:
│    1: variable "storage_class" {
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.storage_class is "abc"
│ 
│ The storage_class must be one of: sc1, sc2, sc3, sc4.
```

Answer (score 0):

@helder-sepulveda's answer has a minor bug - validation will fail when all variables are set to `"false"`

Here's a working example:

```hcl
variable "sc1_default" {
  default = "true"
}

variable "sc2_default" {
  default = "false"
}

variable "sc3_default" {
  default = "false"
}

variable "sc4_default" {
  default = "true"
}

provider "null" {}

locals {
  joined_scs    = join("", [var.sc1_default, var.sc2_default, var.sc3_default, var.sc4_default])
  scs_are_valid = replace(local.joined_scs, "false", "") == "true"
}

resource "null_resource" "validation" {
  lifecycle {
    precondition {
      condition     = local.scs_are_valid
      error_message = "One and only one SC should be set to true."
    }
  }
}
```

Running `terraform plan`:

```txt
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

│ Error: Resource precondition failed
│ 
│   on main.tf line 27, in resource "null_resource" "validation":
│   27:       condition     = local.scs_are_valid
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.scs_are_valid is false
│ 
│ One and only one SC should be set to true.
```

Comment: I covered that in my answer `I'm assuming that all false is OK` and after that `if not you can change that logic to check that is precisely one`

Comment: @HelderSepulveda but that's not what the OP asked: `Looking for a way to validate that only one of 4 storage classes variable is set to "true"`

Comment: Exactly question says: `validate that only one of 4 storage classes variable is set to "true".` I think is safe to assume that all four false is OK, if not the question should explicitly say that it must be exactly one, also the fact the OP provided sample code with all false reinforce my interpretation that all false is acceptable... but at the end is just an interpretation english is not my native language... your validation using string replacement is an interesting approach

Comment: @HelderSepulveda OP provided sample code with all variables set to `false` by default, but if I'm not mistaken his intention is to set one of these to `true` in file `terraform.tfvars` - check the end of his question.

Comment: the end you mean `sc3_default = "true"` that still does not confirm that it must be exactly one, I stand by my interpretation that all false is OK ... and I clearly clarify my assumption in my answer ... regardless, now @JonLinux has multiple great examples he can learn from